# Answers as comments are correct, but no answers on questions - what to do?

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, answers

I'm browsing through the unanswered questions area of the site and I've come across at least a three questions that have correct answers in the comments area and even suggested correct by the OP.

What's the proper procedure here?

- Do I make an answer to the question and mark it as community (so I don't look like I'm poaching)
- Same as above but non-community?
- Add a comment for the person who answered to make it an answer?

Most of these *answers* are of the "It's not possible" variety.

Thoughts, suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple starting line should suffice,

> As also mentioned by @abc, xyz is not possible. Having looked at help section 1, community section 2 and website 3 there does not seem to be any solutions to this.

For extra brownie points, you could state why you think this occurs or point to a feature request section for that app.

Comment: ya, just as I did for a few of your questions.